# access modifiers C# - internal modifier

Tags: c#, oop

From MSDN ,Internal : Access is limited to the current assembly.

so if i have single project winform1 , will using internal modifier mean access to any class in my project?

I mean in a single project , will the current project context and current assembly mean the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a single project , will the current project context and current assembly mean the same?

Yes.

As long as you really have only 1 project, `internal` and `public` are the same. But do realize that in any non-trivial project you sooner or later will want to sub-divide in multiple assemblies. So you might as well prepare for that and use these modifiers correctly. That means make (almost) every class `internal`. It is the default for a reason.